# SD card image created by mksdcard (android SDK tool) corrupted?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdcard

I am using Android Studio on Windows 10.
I created an SD card image (file named SD_Card001.img) with `mksdcard.exe`.
I understood that the file system format is `FAT32`.

1) Is FAT32 the same file system format as the one
on normal/real SD card which are found in smartphones?

2) What is the format of the image itself - is it img or iso?

3) I cannot mount this image for some reason. I wanted to mount this image
with Daemon Tools lite and copy a few files there (to the SD card image),
but I cannot do it. It keeps saying the image is corrupted. Any idea why?

I went through the doc page but it's very short, doesn't mention everything.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/mksdcard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the image format is `QCOW2` with a `YAFFS2` or `FAT32` file-system.

this is not always an "external storage" `SD` card, but it can also emulate an "internal storage" `MMC`.

> One disadvantage of QCOW images is that they cannot be mounted directly as raw disk images would.

therefore `sdcard.img.qcow2` needs to be converted; where `sdcard.img` is the raw backing file:

```
qemu-img convert -p -O raw sdcard.img.qcow2 sdcard.raw
```

the concrete type of the contained file-system may vary:

[image: Virtual SD Card Setup]

in order to display information about an image:

```
qemu-img info sdcard.img.qcow2
```

one can even convert them to virtual disk containers `.vmdk`, `.vdi`, `.vpc`:

```
qemu-img convert sdcard.raw -O vmdk sdcard.raw.vmdk
```

here's the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/qemu-img).

Comment: OK thanks... What are these tools, first time I hear of them? Are they part of the Android SDK. Do they work on Windows? Are you sure the file system is YAFFS2? All examples I found suggest that the file extension should be `.img` but I find no official record if it's really `.img`

Comment: @peter.petrov now this answer is less "maybe"; just had a closer look... `qemu-img` is part of the Android SDK and I guess Daemon Tools should be able to mount the `.raw` image alike an `.img`.

Comment: Hm, OK, thanks but I don't see any qemu-img in my Android SDK. I am on Windows, not sure if it matters.